# How can I auto populate a picklist from Contact to Opportunity

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, administration

I made a picklist in "Lead" that have some values ​​available to be selected. (I did the same picklist with the same values ​​available in "Contact and Opportunity" one per object, so there are in 3 in total).

I mapped the "Lead" record (Picklist) with the other 2 records (Picklist) in "Contact/Opportunity". So at this point... Once you converted the Lead into a "Contact/Opportunity" the records (Picklist) that are in "Contact/Opportunity" receive the same value that has been seleceted before in "Lead".

At this point, it's all working correctly. But the detail and issue that I want to solve, it's that the sales team, wants to be able to change the value of the "Contact" record (Picklist), just in case if it's neccesary. They want that the "Oppportunity" receive automatically the same value that they selected in "Contact" (This will happen after the Lead converted process), so the "Lead maping" would not be an option.

I just want to achieve this... If a choose a value in the picklist from "Contact" object, I want to auto-populate the picklist with the same value in the "Opportunity" object. Someone could guide me, please? I'll really appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to exploit the junction record created between Contact and Opportunity called `OpportunityContactRole` - so, when the Contact picklist changes, you can find the related Opportunities and change their picklist too.  You have to consider that a given Contact could be on multiple `OpportunityContactRole`, each with a different Opportunity so there's a business logic issue to consider

Answer (score 0):

There can be few ways to do that. First you can achieve it by writing trigger on contract and based on field change you can update the opportunity.

Other way could be you can create a record triggered flow and using flow you can achieve this as well.

I will suggest you to go with flow because there you don't need to write code.

Comment: Great, thank you @darkshadowrule just a doubt... I'm making the flow right now. In the first section "Object" I set it "Contact". Then in "Trigger the Flow When" I set it "A record is updated"... In 2nd place at "A record is updated" I set it as "All Conditions Are Met", but what shoul I set later in the criteria? Can you give me a hand, please?